# How to replace childnode inside groovy request

Tags: xml, groovy, replace

In my SOAP request, I have a choice dropdown I have to choose based on my data but i am not sure how to choose in the soap request, thats why i thought of replacing childnode based on my condition.

I have tried nodereplace method but it did't work.

Can someone please help to choose choice dropdown or help me to replace child node with the value

Comment: def assets = new XmlSlurper().parseText(request)
assets.xx.xx.xx.xx.Acctxxtls.xx.find {it.name.text() == 'xxx' }. replaceNode {
    xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx{
        name("MyPackageName")
        
    }
}

Comment: Please provide [mcve]